# Show loading image until dynamic content is available and new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is what I need to do.

I have a php page wich generates a page like site.com/result.php?id=355 plus there is dynamic content fetched from a MySql database.

The problem: The user is redirected to that page before the content even exists in the Mysql database (it is still processed on server side). This means the user has to refresh the page few times for about 3 sec and the results are there.

I want to show a loading image while there is nothing to display until the content is in the database. Once the content can be displayed it should be printed automatically without the user having to refresh page manually.

Code : 
File upload and redirect:
    
          ">

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
                      <input name="userfile" type="file"  id="exampleInputFile">
                      <p class="help-block">Select File To Crypt.</p>
                     <!--  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE_BIND" value="10485760" />
                      <input name="binded" type="file"  id="exampleInputFile">
                      <p class="help-block">Select File To Bind</p> -->
                      <p>
                          <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn full-width btn-primary">Crypt and Scan</button>
                      </p> 
                      </form>
<?php  
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
} else 
{   
mysql_connect("localhost", "scarr", "12345") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("scar");

    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/upl/';
$_rand = generateRandomString();
$_namerand = $_rand . ".exe" ;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir .$_namerand ;


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
if ($_FILES['MAX_FILE_SIZE']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['MAX_FILE_SIZE']['error'] == 0)
{

}
$linked = "http://192.168.129.137/upl/" . $_namerand;
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Task (link, name) VALUES ('$linked', '$_rand')");
if (!$sql) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

 ?>
<form name='redirect' action='result.php?name=' method='GET'>
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo $_rand; ?>'>


<script type='text/javascript'>
document.redirect.submit();
</script>
</form> 
<?php

} else {

}




} 

function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
?>
```

Code Result page:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "scar", "12345") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("scanner");
$namestr = $_GET["name"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,Result FROM Results WHERE name = '$namestr'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);




?>

<div id="content">
<h1><center><font color="green">{ 0/42 }</font></center></h1>
          <table><thead><th>LiveGr Name</th><th>Result</th></thead>
          <tr><td>LiveGridSys </td><td><font color ='Red'><?php printf($row[2])?></font></td></tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Is the content being created in the database based on the user's action on the previous page?

Comment: Code has been added as requsted

Comment: the contet is created from another server and sent to the mysql database.it takes 3-4 seconds for the server to send the results.